# For $QR$ decomposition, does R always have to be upper triangular matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition

$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1  &2 \\ 
 0&0  &1 \\ 
1 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix}$

I have that matrix, and I want to find $QR$ decomposition. So that I choose second column

$q_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}
1  \\ 
 0 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

as my first orthonormal vector, and it is natural to find the other ones

$q_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 
 0 \\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$
$q_{3}=\begin{bmatrix}
0  \\ 
 1 \\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

such that
$Q= \begin{bmatrix}
0&1  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &1 \\ 
1 &0  &0 
\end{bmatrix} \to Q^{T}= \begin{bmatrix}
0&0  &1 \\ 
 1&0  &0 \\ 
0 &1  &0 
\end{bmatrix} $

thus, $Q^{T}A=R= \begin{bmatrix}
1 &0  &0 \\ 
 1&1  &2 \\ 
0 &0  &1 
\end{bmatrix} $

and if I did not make any mistake R is not upper triangular. Is this possible ?

Comment: but im asking what is wrong with what I did ?

Comment: Yes, $R$ must be upper triangular in $QR$ factorization, it is how the [Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process) works. Your choice of $Q$ is not canonical.

Comment: In a QR decomposition, the first orthonormal vector must be a multiple of the first column.  So, choosing the second column is incorrect.